# Use uglifyjs in Publish Profile

Tags: msbuild, uglifyjs

This is a snippet of my Publish Profile:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(_PackageTempDir)"
      Command="uglifyjs ..\..\..\..\js\file1.js ..\..\..\..\js\file2.js --mangle --reserved &quot;$&quot; --compress &gt; js\outfile.min.js" />
```

Certain files (say file1.js) is located outside my project and therefore is not copied to the _PackageTempDir. Here I have to ..\ up several levels to get there. I'm wondering if there is a good way to use an ItemGroup or full path that will allow me the same results.

The above code "works". It is just complicated and difficult to maintain. Looking for a better solution.

EDIT:

Based on Sayed's suggestions, I refined my profile to:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <UglifyJSFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\mcm\mcm.js" />
    <UglifyJSFiles Include="$(_PackageTempDir)\js\main.js" />
</ItemGroup>

<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(_PackageTempDir)"
      Command="uglifyjs @(UglifyJSFiles,' ') &gt; js\app.min.js" />
```

But I am running into an issue because the paths contain spaces. How can I either quote the path strings or escape the spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example showing a better approach

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <JsFilesToUglifyRoot Condition=" '$(JsFilesToUglifyRoot)'=='' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..\..\..\js\</JsFilesToUglifyRoot>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <JsFilesToUglify Include="$(JsFilesToUglifyRoot)**\*.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
      <Message Text="Files: [@(JsFilesToUglify,' ')]" Importance="high" />
      <!-- If you need to quote the file paths use the transform below -->
      <Message Text="Files: [@(JsFilesToUglify->'&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;',' ')]" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

Here I define a new property `JsFilesToUglify` that is populated with the path you indicated above. Note the usage of the `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` reserved property. You should not rely on just `..\` as its value may be different in VS versus outside of VS. Also do not use the `MSBuildProjectDirectory` property, only `MSBuildThisFileDirectory`.

Then inside of the target I transform the list of files with `@(JsFilesToUglify,' ')`  the `,' '` makes a space the separator between values like your command above.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much! One question - can you explain the ** syntax? I understand that *.js is a wildcard for all .js files. But what is the ** before the slash?

Comment: This method does not seem to work for me. I am going to edit the question with some new code reflecting your suggestion.

Comment: @maxmoore14 I've updated my answer. You should spend some time learning more about MSBuild basics. I have some articles out there as well as my books http://msbuildbook.com. If you spend a bit of time on that it will save you time in the future.